# How do I declare a view so it's initialization and itself are NOT in the representable view?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, mapbox-ios, uiviewrepresentable

I have a UIKit representable view for using Mapbox in my SwiftUI app and control the mapView from inside the Coordinator by passing the MapboxViewRepresentable View itself when making the coordinator.

The problem I am having is that the mapView, its coordinator and subscriptions are all being created TWICE! While trying to figure out what the problem was someone commented that my problem was **"holding on to the view in a variable in the representable. Then the initialization and the view are in the make. Don’t put it on a variable at struct level"**

So I adjusted my code and passed the mapView inside makeUIView instead of declaring it in MapboxMapViewRepresentable and used didSet inside of the Coordinator to create/save the subscriptions once the view was passed.

Since I need to manipulate the environmentObjects via MapboxMapViewRepresentable.Coordinator methods, I have a control property (*also REQUIRED by super.init()* ) declared in the Coordinator.

I have no idea why everything is still being created twice, I don't think the fact I used extensions is doing it??

Anything else I could think of to check???

Thank you

**PARENT STRUCT & REPRESENTABLE**

```
struct MapboxMapView: View {
    @ObservedObject var mapVM : MapViewModel
    @ObservedObject var popupVM : PopupProfileViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            MapboxMapViewRepresentable()
                .environmentObject(self.mapVM)
                .environmentObject(self.popupVM)
        }
    }
}

struct MapboxMapViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore
    @EnvironmentObject var mapVM : MapViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var popupVM: PopupProfileViewModel
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        let coordinator = Coordinator(control: self)
        return coordinator
    }
        
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MGLMapView {
        let view = MGLMapView(frame: .zero, styleURL: URL(string: MAPBOX_STYLE_URL))
        context.coordinator.mapView = view
        view.showsUserLocation = true
        view.setCenter(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: mapVM.usersCurrentLat, longitude: mapVM.usersCurrentLong), zoomLevel: MapViewModel.startAtZoomLevel, animated: false)
        view.delegate = context.coordinator
        view.maximumZoomLevel = MapViewModel.maxZoomLevel
        view.allowsRotating = false
        view.direction =  0.0
        view.allowsTilting = false
        mapVM.zoomLevel = view.zoomLevel
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, context: Context) { }
    
}
```

**Coordinator (extension of MapboxMapViewRepresentable)**

```
extension MapboxMapViewRepresentable {

    class Coordinator: NSObject  {
        var control: MapboxMapViewRepresentable
        let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
        
        // MARK: NEW
        var mapView : MGLMapView? {
           didSet {
               guard let mapView = mapView else { return }

                // all of these run twice since map and coordinator are created twice
               control.mapVM.placePublisher.sink { bool in
                   guard let self = self else { return }
                   // control.mapVM.doSomething
                   print(bool)
               }.store(in: &subscriptions)
               
               Self.showRandomPlace.sink { location in
                  // mapView.setCenter....
                  // control.popupVM.doSomething()
                   print(location)
               }.store(in: &subscriptions)

               control.mapVM.newUserSelectedPublisher.sink { nearestPlaceCoords in
                   DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       mapView.zoomLevel = 15.9
                       mapView.setCenter(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: nearestPlaceCoords.lat, longitude: nearestPlaceCoords.long), animated: false)
                   }
               }.store(in: &subscriptions)
           }
        }
        
        // publishes zoomLevel with coordiantor method regionIsChanging to update viewModel with current zoomLevel
        let zoomLevelPublisher = PassthroughSubject<Double, Never>()
        
        var previosZoomLevel = MapViewModel.maxZoomLevel
             
        init(control: MapboxMapViewRepresentable) {
            self.control = control
            super.init()
            setupLocationManager()
            
            // set inital map view's center to user's/device's current location
            if let coordinate = locationManager.location?.coordinate  {
                guard let mapView = mapView else { return }

                self.setCenterAt(coordinate: coordinate)
                control.mapVM.mapCenterCoordinate = mapView.centerCoordinate
            }
        } // END INIT
        
        deinit {
            subscriptions.forEach{$0.cancel()}
            subscriptions.removeAll()
        }
    }
}
```

**How delegate methods are declared**

```
extension MapboxMapViewRepresentable.Coordinator  {
   
    func mapView(_: MGLMapView, didFinishLoading style: MGLStyle) {
        print("DID FINISH LOADING STYLE")
        
        self.control.mapVM.didFinishLoadingUrlStyle = true
        
        self.control.mapVM.loadCurrentUsersPlaces()
        self.control.mapVM.loadNearestPlaces()
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a reference to the `UIView` to your `Coordinator`. That might look like this:

```
struct MapboxMapViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore
    @EnvironmentObject var mapVM : MapViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var popupVM: PopupProfileViewModel
   
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        let coordinator = Coordinator(control: self)
        return coordinator
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MGLMapView {
        let view = MGLMapView(frame: .zero, styleURL: URL(string: MAPBOX_STYLE_URL))
        context.coordinator.mapView = view
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, context: Context) {
        //code
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject  {

        let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        var control: MapboxMapViewRepresentable
        var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
        
        var mapView : MGLMapView? = nil {
            didSet {
                // subscriber receives data via publisher to manipulate map
                mapView?.addAnnotations.sink { annotations in
                    //annotation sink
                }.store(in: &subscriptions)
            }
        }

        init(control: MapboxMapViewRepresentable) {
            self.control = control
            super.init()
            setupLocationManager()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this mean I can get rid of the control property in the coordinator?? Thank you!

Comment: Likely, yes -- unless you have to manipulate something else (like one of the environment objects) via that property.

Comment: You rock! Much appreciated

Comment: I passed the reference in makeUIView just like in your code and am using control because it is required by super.init() in the coordinator and since the view has environmentObjects I need to manipulate but the view/coordinator is still being created twice??? I have no idea why...

Comment: @Chris you would need to post a [mre] to debug this. It is most likely a side effect of something not reflected in the code you've represented so far.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `@ObservedObject ` and `@EnvironmentObject` annotations from everywhere (since nothing you've shown is relying on those updates anyway)?

Comment: I'm going to create a new question because I think I need to give more context....

Comment: Why not edit this one to include a [mre]?

Comment: Got it!, thanks

Comment: Just updated, there is a lot of code so I tried to make it understandable...

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not a [mre] -- it depends on types (like `PopupProfileViewModel` and `SessionStore`) that aren't included here. Can you create a *minimal* example (doesn't include any functions unnecessary to represent the issue) that can be pasted into Xcode (assuming that the person has MapBox added)?